# Python multiprocessing list while updating same pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I would like to parse a large file (around 13Gb) and use multiprocessing to speed things up.
I would like to parse over the file and count each occurrence of a special string and count it within the pandas dataframe.

I know that while doing multiprocessing the handling of shared memory is kind of tricky.

The pseudocode would look like this:

```
with open(input, 'r') as input, Pool(no_cores_to_use) as pool:

            pool.map(
                partial(processDf, df=df),
                (line for line in input),
            )
```

is there some smart way? Would the multiprocesspandas package be useful?

Comment: Split the file into equal parts(num_cpus) and search through that using multiprocessing and sum up the results?

Comment: Do you have enough memory to load the dataframe?

Comment: I have only 4 GB RAM, so thats why I used the dataframe in the first place, as it did not take much RAM and I could loop over the file and count the occurrences of the Strings

Comment: If this is a CSV file that is too large to be read into memory using `pandas`, then I think you will be better of just opening it up with the `csv` module and read it in line by line counting occurrences and forget about multiprocessing or multithreading or any other *elegant* approach.